# 301 redirect from htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, permalinks

I'm trying to create permanent redirects for outdated URL's on my site.

For example I have: www.mydomain.com/?v=tv and want it have a permanent 301 redirect to www.mydomain.com/tv.php

I tried this code in my htaccess file but it did not work:

```
Redirect /?v=tv http://mydomain.com/tv.php
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^tv.php$ http://guessthelogo.com/?v=tv [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That code gave me an invalid page error when trying to visit the site from any angle.....

Comment: sorry. my mistake. changed the answer. try it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing "301" after "Redirect":

```
Redirect 301 /?v=tv http://guessthelogo.com/tv.php
```

Comment: sorry i did not mention i have tried both with and with out 301 in the same format.

Comment: Check out this website, might be helpful http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F

Comment: Yeah I have used that site under: Redirect an old file to a new file path: